# Access WebMatrix (IIS Express) hosted site using external IP

Tags: wordpress, external, webmatrix, iis-express

I've created a WordPress site using WebMatrix Beta on a Windows 7 machine. I'd like to test the site on some mobile devices. Is it possible to configure WebMatrix Beta (IIS Express) to be visible to external devices? I'm sure I read a @scottgu post that suggested it was possible, but can't find it now.

Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a blog post I found that explains where this is at and how to set it up:
http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx

HTH

Jason